# Mingw32 make command: Unrecognized option -z

Tags: c, bash, mingw

I'm trying to **make** this project using Mingw32:

[GitHub PNG2POS](https://github.com/petrkutalek/png2pos)

For that, I'm doing the following command using git bash:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/petrkutalek/png2pos.git
```

It creates a folder called png2pos containing the project sources, and an important file called Makefile.

---

From there, I cd into the newly create folder, and try to execute the command

```
make
```

The expected result was the sources being built into an executable file, but I'm getting some errors that don't allow me to to that:

```
(...)/x86_64-pc-cygwin-bin/ld: unrecognized option '-z'
use the --help option for usage information
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:36: recipe for target 'png2pos' failed
mingw32-make: *** [png2pos] Error 1
```

---

---

What am I supposed to do for this to work and create my desired executable file?

Comment: ascertain what the `-z` option to `ld` was attempting to do in your `makefile`, replace that functionality with something supported by your cygwin.  `man ld` on your installation would be a good second step.

Comment: I managed to build it by editing the Makefile as follows: (1) Comment out or remove the `LDFLAGS += -Wl,-z,now -Wl -z,relro` line. (2) Remove the `-fstack-protector` option from the `CFLAGS` options. (3) Change `@` to `@.exe` on the `@-strip` line.

Comment: @IanAbbott Could you post it as an answer? Also, do you know what is wrong?

Comment: @MoisesCol Sorry, I hit 'return' too early. Edited now. :)

Comment: It worked. Could you please change your comment to an answer, so I can accept it and help future users? (Also, thank you very much! This was stressing me :D)